# PublicKey.load_pkcs1 for Java

Tags: java, scala, encryption, public-key-encryption

I am looking to load a PEM public key to encrypt a value. In Python I would just use a higher level function like `PublicKey.load_pkcs1`. I cannot find such a function for the Java/Scala anywhere.

Is such available or do I need to reimplement following the Python implementation?

---

**EDIT:**

The content is:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: You need to read up on Java encryption libraries. Maybe Google "java load pem to encrypt"?

Comment: I did that but I probably need more information/guidance than what the docs provide

Comment: Will this help? https://www.veracode.com/blog/research/encryption-and-decryption-java-cryptography

Comment: "PEM public key" is not enough detail because PEM is not a single format. For example, what does the first line say (usually -----BEGIN <something>-----").

Comment: Ok, so that is in fact a PKCS 1 public key as you indicated. Unfortunately Java's can only handle a different format for public keys using its X509EncodedKeySpec class. If you use the Bouncycastle library it can read these with a PEMReader instance. Otherwise, there are answers here on SO that show the steps needed to read this in without a third-party library.

Comment: I cannot find a single proper example where one reads a pkcs1 public key and uses it to encrypt a value using _modulus_ and _exponent_ anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Making this work is quite simple.
You only need to call a Python script from Scala like so:

```
val encryptedValue: String = Seq("python3", "foobar.py", pemKey, value).!!
```

In Python you can then simply implement PKCS1 reading via:

```
import base64
import rsa
import sys

pemKey = sys.argv[1]
value = sys.argv[2]
pk = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(bytes(pemKey, 'utf-8'))
encrypted = base64.b64encode(
    rsa.encrypt(value.encode('utf-8'), pk)).decode('utf-8')
print(encrypted)
```